# How to display number to two decimal places, even zero .00 using BC or DC

Tags: bash, floating-point, numbers, zero, bc

This is working properly:

```
echo "scale=2; $a/$b" | bc
```

until $a is very small and $b is very big for example: `$a=1`, `$b=1000000`

In that case it returns only `0`, but I want `.00`.
How can I solve that?

Comment: did I delete your answer or you did it? You answered on my question, I vote up, I hope that I didn't press wrong button. Your answer was printf "%0.2f\n" $(bc -q <<< scale=2\;$a/$b) I don't remeber your name

Comment: I deleted my comment and marked this question now as duplicate.